# how to call a controller method from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call a controller method from my view passing some values from the view to the controller method. How can i collect those values and pass them to the controller method and call the method?

Comment: at MVC architecture is not a good practice to call a Controller function from a view.

Answer (score 1):

Put  the Controller function you are calling in a helper